# How do I get the value of Theme preference from Appearance preference page on Eclipse product?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, preferences

On startup of eclipse product, I just want to get the eclipse UI preference value of Theme.

I tried with the below snippet, but it is returning an empty string value

```
Platform.getPreferencesService().getString("org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages.Views", "Theme", "",
                    null);
```

[image]

It would be great, If I am get this answer.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this from the `IThemeEngine`:

```java
IThemeEngine engine = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IThemeEngine.class);
if (engine != null) {
    ITheme activeTheme = engine.getActiveTheme();
    if (activeTheme != null) {
        // The theme id
        String themeId = activeTheme.getId();
        // The display label
        String label = activeTheme.getLabel();
     
        ...
    }
}
```

`IThemeEngine` can also be injected in an e4 part or obtained from the `IEclipseContext`